# Amazon SP-API retrieve Amazon shipments by order number

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Is there a call in the new Amazon SP-API to retrieve all shipments for a given order, where you don't have the shipment numbers yet?

I'm using the SP-API to create shipments for Ship by Amazon on Prime orders. All good.

However sometimes our users will go on to Seller Central and manually cancel shipments and make new ones (maybe if multiple shipments are required), is there any way for the API to retrieve these shipments? Basically get shipments by order Id. I can't seem to find it in the docs.